# Using Chrome, PDFs sometimes download other times open in Chrome -- other answers to this topic do not address my situation

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, laptop

I use a standalone laptop (not networked, no server), using the current/most recent version of Chrome. My content>PDF setting is to "download PDFs" (i.e. NOT open in chrome), yet some PDFs open in Chrome, while others download. Given I've set PDFs to download, what specifically do I have to do to insure that ALL PDFs download?

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: You can't (at least not that I know of with today's version)

Long answer: When the server sends you the file, he may or may not specify a `Content-Disposition` header. There are three outcomes:

- The server sends none: Chrome will do as told
- The server sends `Content-Disposition: attachment`(with or without a `filename` decorator): Chrome will save the file
- The server sends `Content-Disposition: inline`: Chrome will open the file

This behaviour does make sense in many circumstances, especially with other file types that chrome can either parse or save, but it can be a nuissance with PDFs.